# File uploading using chunking : Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can any one please let me know will jmeter support performance testing for file uploads more than 10gb files. The way the files are uploading is through chunking in JAVA. I cannot do the file upload for more than 10 GB because int allows max size of 2^31. In the http sampler i am declaring the file size as one one chunk 
for eg: file size is 444,641,856 bytes, I am declaring the whole in one chunk instead of dividing it into chunks of 5mb each.

The developers are not willing to change the code and also if I give the result using one chunk size its not a valid performance test.

Can anyone suggest will jmeter allowing chunking mechanism ..... and also is there a solution for file uploading for more than 10Gb Files

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically JMeter doesn't have 2GB limitation (especially HTTPClient implementations) so given you [configured it properly](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)  you shouldn't face errors.

However if you don't have as much RAM as 10GB x number of virtual users you might want to try [HTTP Raw Request](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/).

References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w%5B1-25%5D
- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html

Comment: Dmitri T thanks for replying, but I need to upload using chunking so does jmeter support chunking (resumable js), I dont think so... but

Comment: but  I guess Jmeter can take the file from a webservice where the chunking is done and then I just need to monitor that jar file using the listeners.